# optimizing parallel loop performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a scenario where I need to iterate a 64 millions of combinations and for each of them perform the same kind of processing logic for 64 thousands items of data.

I have noticed, that depending on how I configure the looping logic - the performance, even in parallel loops, can decrease or increase.

Here are 3 scenarios:

common data:

```
int numberofSets = 3;

int set1ElementCount = 5840;
int set2ElementCount = 5840;
int set3ElementCount = 2;

int combinationsCount = 68211200; // = 5840 * 5840 * 2
int dataCount = 64000;
```

1. **Parallel execution**

code:

```
int[,] combinations = new int[combinationsCount, numberofSets];
// combinations = generator.Generate(); // generate combinations
/* generated format is:
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[1,0,0]
...
[5839, 5839, 1]
*/
//itterate combinations
Parallel.For(0, combinationsCount, (idx, state) =>
{
    int idx1 = combinations[idx, 0]; // a bit of hardcoding here since we have 3 sets of data
    int idx2 = combinations[idx, 1];
    int idx3 = combinations[idx, 3];

    // proccess data set for each combination
    for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Results:

- > ~15 minutes to process 1% of data

  2. **Parallel execution 2**

code:

```
// itterate set 1 in parallel
Parallel.For(0, set1ElementCount, (idx1, state) =>
{
    // itterate set 2
    for (int idx2 = 0; idx2  < set2ElementCount; idx2 ++)
    {
        // itterate set 3
        for (int idx3 = 0; idx3  < set3ElementCount; idx3 ++)
        {
            // proccess data set for each combination
            for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Results:

- > ~10 minutes to process 1% of data

  3. **Single-threaded execution**

Code:

```
// itterate set 1
for (int idx1 = 0; idx1 < set1ElementCount; idx1 ++)
{
    // itterate set 2
    for (int idx2 = 0; idx2  < set2ElementCount; idx2 ++)
    {
        // itterate set 3
        for (int idx3 = 0; idx3  < set3ElementCount; idx3 ++)
        {
            // proccess data set for each combination
            for(int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

- > more than 25 minutes to process 1% of data

It is well understandable that the single-thread approach is the slowest. My main concern is multi-threaded performance an it's optimization.

I can explain the execution difference between 1 and 2, by the fact that it takes a bit of time to spawn a new thread. Therefore even if the data itself is processed quickly -  it would still might not be efficient to create and remove threads.

Second conclusion is that - **sometimes** it makes sense to put a higher CPU load per 1 thread (as in case 2), so there wouldn't be any unnecessary time spent on new thread creation.

Now, we are at the point where I ask a question.

How do I find this limit or the data amount that needs to be processed per 1 thread, for the best performance? Is there an approach out there that would allow me to determine - how much of a work is best done for 1 thread?

For example, in the example above I only had 3 sets, two of which are equal. It could have been 10 sets, each having a different about of data. In that case there would be 100 combinations, how you can configure loops:

> set 1 in parallel - rest are single threaded
>
> set 2 in parallel - rest are single threaded
>
> set 1 + 2 in parallel - rest are single threaded
>
> ...

Does that maybe make sense to use some kind of other approach for best looping performance? Thread queue? Tasks?

**Edit:** As was suggested by @arekzyla - I tried to split data into chunks! For that I needed to change combinations array type from `jagged` to `multidimensional` and then do the chunking logic:

```
var combinationsCount = combinations.Length;
int coreCount = 4;
int chuncSize = combinationsCount / coreCount;
List<int[][]> chunked = new List<int[][]>();
for (int i = 0; i < coreCount; i++)
{
    int skip = i * chuncSize;
    int take = chuncSize;

    int diff = (combinationsCount - skip) - take;
    if (diff < chuncSize)
        take = take + diff;

    var sub = combinations.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray();

    chunked.Add(sub);
}

// iterate chunks - each on a separate core
Parallel.For(0, coreCount, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = coreCount }, (chunkIndex, state) =>
{
    var chunk = chunked[chunkIndex];
    int chunkLength = chunk.Length;

    // iterate combinations per-chunk
    for (int idx = 0; idx < chunkLength; idx++)
    {
        // itterate data here
    }
}
```

Results:

> ~9 minutes

Well, a bit of an improvement is still an improvement. Although,I was hoping for something more.

Comment: Just reading this question diagonally, I think you are suffering from locality. You have 2D array and you are accessing columns. The arrays are saved row-wise and loaded in cache. I will look more when I have time and if no one has answered already.

Comment: Maybe try to divide your array into n chunks where n is the number of cores you have and start n threads each calculating one chunk of data in a for loop. Then you will get the most out of your CPU and spend little time on creating threads (only n)

Comment: Your second approach is similar to the second example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop. That page suggests parallelizing any loop with a large dataset, so maybe try parallel the first two.

Comment: @arekzyla I am trying out this approach now!

Comment: @arekzyla you can check my implementation in the edit section. Improvement is within a scope of an error. A very tiny improvement.

Comment: @Alex did you take into account also logical cores or only physical? Instead of `coreCount` I would use `Environment.ProcessorCount` to get the right number

Comment: @arekzyla I used a total count of cores (2 physical and 2 logical)

Comment: @Alex so all the cores are stressed 100% and the thread creation cost is minimal so I don't believe you can achieve any better result. If you need to do such heavy calculation maybe you should try to implement it on GPU?